# cytoscape.js has cy.load but is there a way to effectively perform a "cy.save()"?

Tags: cytoscape.js

We're looking at creating an editor app with cytoscape.js - using interactions to create new nodes, edges etc, so we need to be able to save the changes (as JSON) back to the server.

I can see cy.load but no equivalent cy.save. Is there a way to effectively perform a a cy.save and sent the JSON stream back to the server for storage?

Comment: See http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/data/eles.jsons: _This function returns the plain JSON representation of all elements in the collection, the same format which is used at initialisation, in cy.load(), in cy.add() etc._

Comment: There is also `cy.json()`, which is on the `cy` level like your `cy.save()` example: http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/export/cy.json